# For good few hours usage

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> "Since the sun is already setting and the town is still for good four
>   hours of ride afar, I think it would be wise to wait the night out
>   here."

Is the use of **"for good few hours"** correct?

Comment: The original sentence does not look correct to this native US English speaker.  I would say something like "the town is still a good four hours' ride".

Comment: Bah, I meant to clarify the proposed edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the question a few times, I understand that

> Since the sun is already setting and the town is still for good four
>   hours of ride afar, I think it would be wise to wait the night out
>   here.

could be better written as

> Since the sun is already setting and the town is still a good four
>   hours ride away, I think it would be wise to wait the night out here.

The phrase "a good four hours" means "at least four hours".

Comment: Yeah. That might be it. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: The use of an apostrophe in "four hours' ride" is debatable, since time cannot own anything. Perhaps better as "a good four hour ride". As in "a four cigarette job" ;)

Comment: The apostrophe doesn't have to mark possession, and in this case it doesn't. *Four-hour* is an adjective that's usually hyphenated. This is true of American English, as well as of other, less represented varieties of English.